# TastyPie and Django ORM - how tightly coupled are they?

Tags: python, django, api, tastypie

Is it possible to develop an API in Django "TastyPie" in a way which doesn't tie it directly to a "single" Django ORM model? i.e. a call /api/xyz/ would retrieve data from "a", "b" & "c" into a single JSON output. If so, please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

tastypie is more tightly coupled to the ORM than django-piston, but there are methods that you can define in a tastypie resource to specify how to handle create, read, update, delete: http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-tastypie/en/latest/resources.html?highlight=put_list#obj-get
And you would just not set the queryset meta field.

django-piston on the other hand, has a more direct initial approach to having you define one or more of these methods. The resource can still be bound to a model to give you out of the box REST, but its more up front about showing you the methods to define for custom handling.

tastypie is a bit more robust in its process and features, but it makes this specific feature set a little less apparent.

Answer (score 1):

Tastypie has `ModelResource` and `Resource`. The former is tied to a model(which you can override a lot of its methods as jdi suggested) and the latter is what you need I think. Example of `Resource` [here](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-tastypie/en/latest/non_orm_data_sources.html). The example is for a Riak data source, in your case it would be a combination of django models.